# Find the remainder when $6^{66^{666}}$ is divided by $71$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've been working with this exercise for a while and I've been able to make some progress. I worked over the $66^{666}$ exponent by replacing it by the remainder of its division by 70 (I found that remainder by finding each of the 70 prime factors' (2, 5 and 7) remainders and then joining them by using the Chinese Remainder Theorem) and I obtained 36. But the fact is that I still stay with $6^{36}$ and I can't figure out a way to simplify that. Is there any way I can avoid calculating the succesive remainders of the different powers of 6 over 71? For instance, can I rewrite $6^{36}$ as the square root of $6^{72}$ (since I know that $6^{36}$ is an integer) and use that (including the square root) in a congruence equation?

Answer (score 3):

$$6^3\equiv3\pmod{71}$$

$$6^{12}\equiv3^4\equiv10\implies6^{36}\equiv10^3\equiv6$$